# Problems importing mbox files to Dovecot sdbox with doveadm

Tags: dovecot, mbox

OK, I need a couple of rep points and I'm about to pull the pin on this...

I'm trying to import some mbox files into a Dovecot sdbox store using something along the lines of:

```
doveadm -D import -u user@example.com mbox:/path/to/mbox "" mailbox INBOX all
```

a) Why can't I specify the mbox file?  `mbox:/mbox-path/inbox.mbox` doesn't work with `mbox: mbox root directory can't be a file` and all that works is renaming the file to `inbox`, using `mbox:/mbox-path` and letting it default to that: `Debug: mbox: INBOX defaulted to /mbox-path/inbox`.

b) So I got it to import to INBOX, but now I can't do `mailbox Sent`.  Renamed sent.mbox to inbox, same default, but it says `Error: Mailbox Sent: Mailbox sync failed: Mailbox doesn't exist: Sent`.  lol wtf, it's right there in front of me (yes, no, not a permissions issue).

The [doveadm](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Import) docs aren't super helpful on this issue.  [Mbox format](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/mbox), nope.  Thought [Dovecot mbox config](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/mbox) had some clues, but nope.

Should I just try to IMAP -> IMAP in some way?  IMAP to something better than mbox and import that?  At least this is personal and not 47M emails or something.  Should I just get the source?

If it matters, it's [2019](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/2019)-05-16 and: [Debian 9](https://debian.org/releases/stretch/) up to date, [dovecot-core 2.2.27](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/dovecot-core), mbox files are from a [Google archive](https://takeout.google.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a trailing slash on the mbox file:
`doveadm -D import -u user@example.com mbox:/path/to/mbox/ Sent all`

That said, I didn't have much luck with doveadm import. It ignored mbox names with non-ASCII characters, and creates files all over the place on the source. I ended up using mb2md.pl, but that's for transferring mbox to Maildir. Not sure what your options are for sdbox.

Comment: Succeeded with this command (to import a mbox file from Debian bugtracker) with the following other caveats.
* I had to put the mbox file in an empty directory and pointing to this directory with the trailing slash.
* It can be put in a subdirectory with 'Folder.Subfolder' in place of 'Sent'.
* I had permission issues, so debug flag is useful for that.
* At the end, it creates a directory named after the mbox file, so if you want to put emails in a specific directory, name the mbox file with that directory name and give the name of the parent directory in the command parameter.